# Implementation of Java OutputStream flush() method

Tags: java, flush

I have a writing thread, using `OutputStream`, and I want to implement a `flush()` method.
[As mentioned in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29),

> The flush method of OutputStream does nothing
>   and should be implemented if needed.

I have the following thread, and I'm a little bit confused about how should I override `flush()`

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                    tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                    tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
         }


        public void write(byte[] buffer) {

            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
               // does nothing
                mmOutStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The doc says that the _base implementation_ of `OutputStream` (which is `abstract` by the way) does nothing; it does not mean that classes _inheriting_ this base class use this base implementation.

Comment: Why do you want to override the `flush()` method of `OutputStream`? Simply use `PrintWriter`, `BufferedWriter` a lots of impl are there.

Comment: Since you want to modify the behavior of a class (implement `flush()`) you need to extend it. You can start by creating your own class that extends some type of `OutputStream` and you should be able to override and implement `flush()` then.

Comment: Indeed. The abstract class is playing the role of template pattern and it's up to concrete classes to decide how the flush is filled in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is about "implementing" `flush()` but your code is not implementing an output stream. I guess you either want to ask about "using" flush() or you miss the fact that `getOutputStream()` returns an implementation of OutputStream which most likely does have a working flush() (in some cases it is an empty implementation because no special handling is needed if the stream is not buffering).

I am not sure what BluetoothSocket you are using, but if it is `android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket` then this is returning a `BluetoothOutputStream` which is forwarding both the write and the flush directly to the BT socket.

Typically you need to call flush() at the end of a single message/packet. You should not call it when you pump lots of data into a stream. (Because if you do you might reduce your throughput and reduce the options for the stream implementation to reduce overhead).